# What is "root:{}" used for?

Tags: html, css

I often see people use this line in CSS at the beginning of the .css code. Can someone explain what is it used for? I know that is used for defining the style of the highest parent, but i dont know what that means.

Answer (score 3):

As you're already aware:

From this page:   [CSS-Tricks :root selector](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/r/root/#:%7E:text=The%20%3Aroot%20selector%20allows%20you,with%20parent%20and%20sibling%20content.)

> The :root selector allows you to target the highest-level “parent” element in the DOM, or document tree.

This page provides syntax as well:  [developer.mozilla :root{}](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:root)

Here's an example you can run:

```css
:root {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  padding: 3em;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<p>We can take advantage of being able to apply CSS to the <code>&lt;html&gt;</code> element to skip the wrapper <code>div</code> and keep our markup clean!</p>
```